# How to count values in a panda dataframe with specific index dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I count with a loop how many 2-up and 2-dn are in a column at the same index date in a panda dataframe?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
index = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-08','2020-01-08','2020-01-08']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = index)
bars = ['1-inside','2-up','2-dn','2-up','2-up','1-inside']
df1['Strat'] = bars
df1
```

Result should be:

- 2020-01-01 2-up = 1, 2-dn = 1
- 2020-01-08 2-up = 2, 2-dn = 0

Afterwards I would like to plot the results with matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for count, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and then plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
need = ['2-up','2-dn']
df1 = df1['Strat'].groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)[need]
print (df1)
Strat       2-up  2-dn
2020-01-01     1     1
2020-01-08     2     0
```

Or you can filter before counts by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
need = ['2-up','2-dn']
df1 = (df1.loc[df1['Strat'].isin(need), 'Strat']
         .groupby(level=0)
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

---

```
df1.plot.bar()
```